# Regex for replacing parameter values in a URL (values between = and &)

Tags: regular-expression

I have a large list (100,000+) of URLS with parameters like so:

```
https://www.example.com?a=b&1=2&me=you
https://www.example.com?a=b
```

I'm using VIM need a regex to replace all values with whatever I desire, like so:

```
https://www.example.com?a=value&1=value&me=value
https://www.example.com?a=value
```

Also, I'm not limited to a Regex, if someone has a solution using norm or sed, that would also work. I just need to be able to automate it.

Comment: `s/\([^&?]*=\)[^&]*/\1value/g`

Comment: That works, just need the %s. You should've answered traditionally so I could mark it answered! Thank you so much though!

Comment: @Quasímodo agreed; this could be an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quasimodo commented the solution, so I'll post here so I can mark this answered:

To replace each value between = and &, and everything after the final =, if it's the last parameter in a URL, for every line in a file, this works:

```
%s/\([^&?]*=\)[^&]*/\replacement/g
```

Comment: You meant `\1replacement`